# I would like to use Firebase OTP with keycloak is it posible?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, keycloak

we are using keycloak as SSO for our eco system. now we would like to provide a Mobile (React Native) app for customers where they can login using their mobile number. unfortunately out of the box keycloak not supporting this scenario. we would like use Firebase SMS Authentication for it. is there any example or else any document to cover this topic will be helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have you checked this documentation [Authenticate with Firebase on Android using a Phone Number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to extend Authentication SPI from keycloak where you can plug in various such implementations.
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi
The above doc also have a sample implementation but not specific to firebase but its relatable.
You would also need to extend the browser flow and add your new firebase step once your implementation is ready. Here is the doc for that
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#configuring-authentication_server_administration_guide